# rails did not auto add "jquery" to the package.json and yarn.lock files even though codes have been added to needed files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I created a very simple Rails program named freelancer and want to use Bulma library and Jquery in this program. So here is what I did.

In the file "Gemfile", I add this lines

`gem ‘bulma-rails’, ‘~> 0.9.4’ gem ‘bulma-extensions-rails’, ‘~> 1.0.30’`

In this file app -> assets -> stylesheets -> application.css

I added this lines

`@import 'bulma'; @import 'bulma-extensions'`

Then I ran these commands

`Bundle install; Yarn add jquery;`

I thought that in these files package.json and yarn.lock, there must be jquery line ? But there are not.

Here is my code, if you need to reference

`https://github.com/nguyencuc2586/freelancer02`

Could you please give me some advices for this problem ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As I see from your github code, there is a jquery line in both package.json and yarn.lock file so I think it installed correctly, but in order to work, jquery needs to be initialized in app/javascript/application.js. I personally initialize it next way:

- Create new file inside app/javascript directory and call jquery.js
- Paste this three line there

```
import jquery from 'jquery'
window.jQuery = jquery
window.$ = jquery
```

- import that file in application.js
  `import "./jquery"`

Now jquery should work as expected